# How to change or set "Configuration Options" in Mediapipe?

Tags: c++, mediapipe

Checked around the documents but didn't find anything regards to a graph's option. I'm using C++ BTW.

Like on this page https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/holistic.html

According to the document, it has following "Configuration Options"
STATIC_IMAGE_MODE, UPPER_BODY_ONLY, SMOOTH_LANDMARKS, MIN_DETECTION_CONFIDENCE, MIN_TRACKING_CONFIDENCE

But I'm failed at find a clear instruction for how exactly to set or modify them.
Only thing I found is an issue regarding modifying them on the fly, someone said to use AddPacketToInputStream with a 'packet' created by AdoptAsUniquePtr, but there is no more details.
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/198

Could someone help point me to the right location for user guides and documents?